# Weird flight path for BA714 - Sep 13, 2018

Tags: air-travel

just noticed this weird flight path and the altitude gain graph. What could be the possible reason?

https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/BA/714?year=2018&month=09&date=13&flightId=973124366

Comment: Educated guess: The flight crew experienced a problem with the plane and decided to return to London. Then they found the problem or it disappeared, so they continue the flight, but now they use a **route over airports** (see the jumps in orientation) so if it happens again they can go down as soon as possible.

Comment: It is just an error. https://www.flightradar24.com/BAW714T/1dd99aed does not have such change. Do no trust automatic sources. Often there are error in the incoming data, or just an error in transmission/database

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Is it? Strangely flight BA8765 (shown as CFE54K) with the same airline, source and destination almost perfectly follows the former predicted flight path, BAW714T flies definitely wrong in both maps.

Comment: @ThorstenS.: I do not understand: one departed from LCY, one from LHR. I trust FR24, which show also the speed (FR24 sometime has such artifact, but you see on speed, that there were some wrong points). on FR24, both flight seems normal. I think on flightstats there were some problem to automatically link transponder with flight number. Or just a problem on the antenna (these data are provided by volunteers, I provide also an antenna for FR24, and we do no live in optimal positions).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel, per se, and might be better asked on [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ThorstenS.: I don' think the grey line is a "predicted flight path" -- just a great-circle line between the scheduled origin and destination.

Comment: I think this is a general problem with FlightStats. [Their tracking of UA5247](https://www.flightstats.com/v2/flight-tracker/UA/5247?year=2018&month=9&date=12&flightId=973078573) does the same thing about every day.

Answer (score 6):

If you zoom in on the Flightstats map, you will see that the apparent initial excursion into Kent is made up of straight lines and impossibly sharp turns. Combined with the fact that Flightradar24 doesn't show any such thing, I conclude that **it is a data error; the plane didn't actually fly to Kent and back to London**.

The Flightradar replay shows that the flight left its Terminal 5A gate at 11:18 UTC, taxied to the runway and took off at 11:36 UTC, and then followed the path via Paris that Flightstats also shows. But Flightstat claims the "actual" departure time as 11:10 UTC. It seems to have invented 20 minutes of teleporting around Kent and Surrey out of thin air.

Possibly Flightstats started by *guessing* where the plane would be, based on its scheduled departure time of 11:10 UTC, and then, when actual position data started coming in, scrambled to connects its initial guess to reality somehow.

Comment: [Flightaware](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/BAW714/history/20180913/1120Z/EGLL/LSZH) doesn't show any odd jogs either, other than the long turn to the southeast after takeoff.